# Change certificate in GCM for iOS

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

During making GCM service for iOS i had to updload signed certificate for push notification for APN (file with .p12). I need to change this certificate to antoher in existing GCM service(server key). Is it possible to make this via google developer console?. If no, how can I do this to not change plist file in released applications.

Comment: If you change your certificate and upload it in the developer console, it will result to a different plist file therefore it is a must that you update your plist file in your released application.

Comment: Why do you need to change your certificate? Can't you use the old one?

Comment: No I use Apple Developer Enterprise certificate to show gcm on customer review(many customer devices, constantly are changing), and other Apple production certficate for appstore app version. Now I have 2 GCM services with two different certificates and in xcode on app build phase script chose which gcm plist should used.

Comment: @Mangus Smith Another thing is that apn Certificate has expired date so when I renew it I consider whether gcm will still working?